# Parse REST API - POST not supported in batch operations

Tags: c#, parse-platform

Iam using C# to call the parse rest api and trying to execute a basic batch create operation is giving me this error

```
"{"code":107,"error":"Method 'POST' to '/1/classes/NewObject/' not supported in batch operations."}
```

I have tried changing my method to PUT but the error just changes to

```
"{"code":107,"error":"Method 'PUT' to '/1/classes/NewObject/' not supported in batch operations."}
```

**NewObject** already exists as a class in my Parse application and has already one record which i created via REST API

**EDIT:**
My Request parameters from c# watcher

```
[0] {Accept=application/json}   RestSharp.Parameter
[1] {X-Parse-Application-Id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}  RestSharp.Parameter
[2] {X-Parse-REST-API-Key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}  RestSharp.Parameter
[3] {application/json={"requests":[{"method":"POST","path":"/1/classes/NewObject/","body":{"name":"luke","element":"Fir"}},{"method":"POST","path":"/1/classes/NewObject/","body":{"name":"tsitsi","element":"qwee"}}]}}    RestSharp.Parameter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `json` in the http's request body if it's well formatted because Parse.com REST Api supports `POST` for batch operations. Please add to your question  detailed  http request you are trying to execute. Try to remove your trailing slash `/` from your path object. Sample:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/1/classes/NewObject",
      "body": {
        "name": "luke",
        "element": "Fir"
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/1/classes/NewObject",
      "body": {
        "name": "tsitsi",
        "element": "qwee"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit, that is the actual request parameters in my watcher window

Comment: Amazing...Thanks mate